# Node/Mongo DB not filtering data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to filter data based on two dates. The issue is when the month are different then it doesn't return any data.

Let's says I'm trying to filter data for one week i.e from current day to 7 days back, the date would be **From** 27.03.2023 and **to** 01.04.2023. Now it doesn't return any data as the date range falls between different months but when I pass **From** 27.03.2023 and **to** 31.03.2023 it returns the records.

One more issue is it doesn't include the last day as well. like it will return data till 30.03.2023 and not till 31.03.2023 even though the ending date is 31.03.2023

I'm using moment js to fetch the dates and using the following code to fetch the date.

```
    const dateTo = moment().format(constants.DATE_FORMAT);
    const dateFrom = moment().subtract(7, 'd').format(constants.DATE_FORMAT);


    const list = (await db.collection(constants.COLLECTION_RECORDS)
        .find({ "userId": req.body.userId, "date": {$gte:dateFrom, $lt:dateTo} })
        .toArray()).reverse();
```

Please point out the issue in this code.
Thank you.

Comment: btw in mongo are you storing dates as strings or date objects or timestamps?

Comment: what is your constants.DATE_FORMAT

Comment: I'm storing the date as strings. The constants.DATE_FORMAT was dd.MM.yyyy but as suggested I've updated it to yyyy-MM-dd and it resolved the issue. Thank you for helping out.